# Laravel | Show/Hide an element according to Roles within vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

<NavLink v-if="value":href="route('accounts')" :active="route().current('accounts')">
Accounts

This is what I wanted to hide. In my user's table the role is defined as either User or Admin.

My thoughts on this is around:

IF USER IS ADMIN VALUE WILL BE CHANGED TO TRUE.

I am stumped on retrieving the data from the database using vue coding.

Attempts were seen using axios and vice versa. But if there is any way that will instead retrieve data and compare in an if statement would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `laravel/breeze with inertia` you can access the current authenticated user data using `usePage()` or `$page`

you can use `usePage()` if you want to use it inside the `<script></script>` tag

```
const isAdmin = computed(() => {
    return usePage().props.auth.user.role === 'Admin'
})
```

then if you want it inside the `template` tag

```
<div v-if="($page.props.auth.user.role === 'Admin')"></div>
```